# vue.js | Transition on dynamic components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to perform transition on dynamic components in vue.js `v2.6.11`. I have referred to the documentation - [Transitioning Between Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Components), but unable to get the results.

I have created a sample in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-dynamic-component-ky8bj8?file=/src/App.vue) with different trial and errors. But below is the basic code snippet that should have been enough to achieve the transition.

**template**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle</button>
    <transition class="component-fade" mode="out-in">
      <component :is="currentComp" val="msg" :key="currentComp" />
    </transition>
    <transition class="component-fade" mode="out-in">
      <div v-if="toggle">test</div>
      <p v-else>Sorry, no items found.</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

**script**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      toggle: true
    };
  },
  components: {
    home2: {
      template: `<h1>home2</h1>`,
    },
    "about-us2": {
      template: `<h1>about2</h1>`,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    currentComp() {
      return this.toggle ? "home2" : "about-us2";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Style**

```
<style scoped>
.component-fade-enter-active,
.component-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 6s ease;
}

.component-fade-enter,
.component-fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Explanation of code:
On click of toggle button, the components will switch using the computed value and the component will change using the `:is` of `<component>`. So, when it changes then am trying to a basic transition (opacity change for now).

Let me know if I am missing anything in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided the `transition name`.

Replace `class="component-fade"`

```
<transition class="component-fade" mode="out-in">
```

with

```
<transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
```

Here is the [fixed sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-dynamic-component-forked-cl4fy8?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: oh correct!! Made a minor mistake. Thank you